# Flattening an array of tuples of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm quite new to `numpy` and the treatment of arrays, and I've encountered the following problem. I have an array that looks something like this:

```
[ (float, array([ float]), array([ float, float]), int, int, float)
  ... ]
```

i.e. it seems to me that each element of the array is a tuple, containing a mix of float, int and arrays of floats. I would like to know 1) how to get rid of any array structure that arises *inside* the tuple keeping only the first index, and 2) what the most efficient way of doing this is.

For instance, if the first tuple is:

```
(1.2, array([ 0.03]), array([ 1.8, 2.1]), 2, 4, 2.)
```

I'd like to get:

```
(1.2, 0.03, 1.8, 2, 4, 2.)
```

Any advice?

Comment: What is the `shape` and `dtype` of this array?  And how did you generate this array?

Comment: @Prune, this is too early to mark this as a duplicate.  We don't know the dtype of this array.  Is this an object dtype?  Structured array?

Comment: Good point.  Reopened; closure vote is more appropriate.

Comment: As I said, I'm quite new to this, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean... Typing `myarray.dtype`, I get the following: `numpy.record, [('var1', '<f4'), ('var2', 'O'), ('var3', 'O'), ('var4', '<i4')...])`

Comment: OK, that's a structured array (actually `record` subclass, but effectively the same), with 2 of fields being object dtype.  I'll have to construct something similar, and play around with various ways of flattening it.  It isn't going to be easy.

Comment: Another question - are the arrays in the tuples all the same shape?  In the example they are (1,) and (2,) shaped.

Comment: @hpaulj I think they could technically be (n,) shaped (just a one-dimensional list treated as an array, if I understand correctly?) but I only ever need to retain the first element.

Comment: Keeping just the first element of the subarrays changes the problem significantly.  Though I'm not sure it makes it easier or harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing a similar structured array:

```
In [333]: dt=[('var1', '<f4'), ('var2', 'O'), ('var3', 'O'), ('var4', '<i4')]
In [334]: arr = np.zeros(3, dt)
In [335]: arr
Out[335]: 
array([(0., 0, 0, 0), (0., 0, 0, 0), (0., 0, 0, 0)],
      dtype=[('var1', '<f4'), ('var2', 'O'), ('var3', 'O'), ('var4', '<i4')])
```

Fill it with data (for now identical copies):

```
In [336]: arr[0]=(1.2, np.array([.03]),np.array([1.8,2.1]),2)
In [337]: arr[1]=(1.2, np.array([.03]),np.array([1.8,2.1]),2)
In [338]: arr[2]=(1.2, np.array([.03]),np.array([1.8,2.1]),2)
In [339]: arr
Out[339]: 
array([(1.2, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2),
       (1.2, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2),
       (1.2, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2)],
      dtype=[('var1', '<f4'), ('var2', 'O'), ('var3', 'O'), ('var4', '<i4')])
```

`tolist` doesn't remove or flatten the inner arrays:

```
In [340]: arr.tolist()
Out[340]: 
[(1.2000000476837158, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2),
 (1.2000000476837158, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2),
 (1.2000000476837158, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2)]
```

With simpler structured dtypes, `np.array(arr.tolist())` often works, since `np.array` tries to create a multidimensional array if it can.  But here the first element is a float, but the second is an array:

```
In [341]: np.array(_)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

We can make an object dtype array from that list - but that still doesn't unpack the inner arrays:

```
In [342]: np.array(arr.tolist(),object)
Out[342]: 
array([[1.2000000476837158, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2],
       [1.2000000476837158, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2],
       [1.2000000476837158, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2]],
      dtype=object)
```

I can unpack the 'var2' field with:

```
In [345]: arr['var2'].astype(float)
Out[345]: array([0.03, 0.03, 0.03])
In [346]: arr['var2'][:] = _
In [347]: arr
Out[347]: 
array([(1.2, 0.03, array([1.8, 2.1]), 2),
       (1.2, 0.03, array([1.8, 2.1]), 2),
       (1.2, 0.03, array([1.8, 2.1]), 2)],
      dtype=[('var1', '<f4'), ('var2', 'O'), ('var3', 'O'), ('var4', '<i4')])
```

But this doesn't work with the 'var3' field.  But if you just want the first element of each 'var3' array:

```
In [353]: arr['var3']
Out[353]: 
array([array([1.8, 2.1]), array([1.8, 2.1]), array([1.8, 2.1])],
      dtype=object)

In [355]: np.stack(arr['var3'])  # only works if all have the same length
Out[355]: 
array([[1.8, 2.1],
       [1.8, 2.1],
       [1.8, 2.1]])
In [356]: np.stack(arr['var3'])[:,0]
Out[356]: array([1.8, 1.8, 1.8])
In [357]: arr['var3']=_
In [358]: arr
Out[358]: 
array([(1.2, 0.03, 1.8, 2), (1.2, 0.03, 1.8, 2), (1.2, 0.03, 1.8, 2)],
      dtype=[('var1', '<f4'), ('var2', 'O'), ('var3', 'O'), ('var4', '<i4')])
In [359]: np.array(arr.tolist())
Out[359]: 
array([[1.20000005, 0.03      , 1.8       , 2.        ],
       [1.20000005, 0.03      , 1.8       , 2.        ],
       [1.20000005, 0.03      , 1.8       , 2.        ]])
```

---

Maybe it's better to treat this array a list of tuples, and process it iteratively.

First, generalize the elements of the array:

```
In [360]: arr[0]=(1.2, np.array([.03]),np.array([1.8,2.1]),2)
In [361]: arr[1]=(1.2, np.array([.03,.4]),np.array([1.8,2.1,.2]),2)
In [362]: arr[2]=(1.2, np.array([.03,.4]),np.array([1.8]),2)
In [363]: arr
Out[363]: 
array([(1.2, array([0.03]), array([1.8, 2.1]), 2),
       (1.2, array([0.03, 0.4 ]), array([1.8, 2.1, 0.2]), 2),
       (1.2, array([0.03, 0.4 ]), array([1.8]), 2)],
      dtype=[('var1', '<f4'), ('var2', 'O'), ('var3', 'O'), ('var4', '<i4')])
```

Define a helper function that pulls the 1st element of an array:

```
In [364]: def foo(item):
     ...:     try:
     ...:         return item[0]
     ...:     except:
     ...:         return item
     ...:
```

Now iterate on the tuples, and within the tuples:

```
In [365]: [[foo(item) for item in a] for a in arr]
Out[365]: [[1.2, 0.03, 1.8, 2], [1.2, 0.03, 1.8, 2], [1.2, 0.03, 1.8, 2]]
```

Turn it back into an array if needed:

```
In [366]: np.array(_)
Out[366]: 
array([[1.20000005, 0.03      , 1.8       , 2.        ],
       [1.20000005, 0.03      , 1.8       , 2.        ],
       [1.20000005, 0.03      , 1.8       , 2.        ]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I keep the dtype structure as it is, but make sure all `object` elements become floats?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using `itertools.chain`. Assumes items are either scalars or `numpy` arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

tup = [(1.2, np.array([ 0.03]), np.array([ 1.8, 2.1]), 2, 4, 2.),
       (5.2, np.array([ 0.345]), np.array([ 11.8, 25.1]), 7, 1, 12.)]

res = list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(i.tolist() \
           if isinstance(i, np.ndarray) else [i] for i in j) for j in tup))

# [1.2, 0.03, 1.8, 2.1, 2, 4, 2.0, 5.2, 0.345, 11.8, 25.1, 7, 1, 12.0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) And how would you go about looping and rewriting the array itself?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. the result is a list.

Comment: I mean that you call `tup` here is one of many tuples inside a numpy array. Can I just manipulate each tuple as an index of the array? or is there something to be done with iterators?

Comment: @Demosthene, you could "chain the chains", see update.